# Using paper_trail to reify acts_as_taggable_on associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines, acts-as-taggable-on, paper-trail-gem

I'm working on a bug on a rails engine using both paper_trail and acts_as_taggable_on. When I rollback a deleted event the event details are restored, but the tags are not. Has anyone came across this same issue?

Some relevant info:

models/calagaor/event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  acts_as_taggable 
end
```

I also created a config/initializers/act_as_taggable.rb file:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.class_eval do
  has_paper_trail
end

ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.class_eval do
  has_paper_trail
end
```

I'm pretty new to rails so I'm not sure if I'm headed in the right direction or not. Let me know if you need more details. Thanks!

Edit:

controllers/calagator/versions_controller.rb

```
module Calagator

class VersionsController < Calagator::ApplicationController
  def edit
    @version = PaperTrail::Version.find(params[:id])
    @record = @version.next.try(:reify) || @version.item ||    @version.reify

    singular =    @record.class.name.singularize.underscore.split("/").last
    plural = @record.class.name.pluralize.underscore.split("/").last
    self.instance_variable_set("@#{singular}", @record)

    if request.xhr?
      render :partial => "calagator/#{plural}/form", :locals => {   singular.to_sym =>  @record }
    else
      render "calagator/#{plural}/edit", :locals => { singular.to_sym =>  @record }
    end
  end
end

end
```

I'm using paper_trail '3.0.8'

Comment: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#diffing-versions

Comment: According to the documentation, "PaperTrail only stores the changes for creation and updates; it doesn't store anything when an object is destroyed." I'm trying to reify the associations on a deleted event.

Comment: That line from the readme is misleading out of context.  It refers to the `changeset` method, not the creation of records in the `versions` table.

Comment: What does your call to `reify` look like, and what version of paper_trail are you using?

Comment: @JaredBeck I just added the versions controller and gem version.

Answer (score 1):

> [How do I use] paper_trail to reify acts_as_taggable_on associations?
>   I'm using paper_trail '3.0.8'

paper_trail 3 doesn't do associations. Try upgrading to paper_trail 4.

Docs: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#associations